# pandas.read_csv cant find my path error

Tags: python, pandas, input, path, virtualenv

So I tried to run this code.

```
import pandas

i = input("hi input a csv file..")

df = pandas.read_csv(i)
```

and I got an error saying

```
FileNotFoundError: File b'"C:\\Users\\thomas.swenson\\Downloads\\hi.csv"' does not exist
```

but then if I hard code that path that 'doesn't exist' into my program it works fine.

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv("C:\\Users\\thomas.swenson\\Downloads\\hi.csv")
```

it works just fine.

Anyone know why this may be happening?

I'm running python 3.6 and using a virtualenv

Answer (score 1):

looks like the input function was placing another set of quotes around the input. 
so ill just have to remove them and it works fine.